# Boost.Spirit: Difference between operators "%=" and "="

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I don't understand the difference between these two operators. Let's take an example parsing inputs like `"AA,BB,CC,DD"` into vector of strings.

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
class my_grammar : public qi::grammar<string::const_iterator, string()>
{
public:
  my_grammar() : base_type(start) {
    using qi::_1;
    using qi::char_;
    start = *(char_ - qi::lit(','));
  }
  qi::rule<string::const_iterator, string()> start;
};
```

As far as I know, the `a %= b` is equivalent to `a = b[_val = _1]`. That's clear. But on the other hand, the parser `*(char_ - qi::lit(','))` has a synthesised attribute of type `std::string` to which the matched sequence will be assigned. The result of using `start = *(char_ - qi::lit(','))` is the same. So what's the case for using operator `%=`?

Comment: It's a faq http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+automatic+propagation+assignment - see also http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/01/15/how-do-rules-propagate-attributes/, http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/attribute-propagation-and-attribute-compatibility/ :)

Comment: @sehe -- how would one proceed to find the matching answer in the FAQ?

Comment: @FrankPuck I stated the question is frequently asked. I didn't mean to imply there's an organized "FAQ" (unless you count this site)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I've found it in boost documentation under [Auto Rules](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.employee___parsing_into_structs.auto_rules):

```
 Note
 r %= p and r = p are equivalent if there are no semantic actions associated with p.
```

So if the `start` rule contained semantic action ex.

```
*(char_[boost::phoenix::ref(my_string) = _1] - qi::lit(','))`
```

then changing the operator to `%=` would enable automatic attribute propagation, which would otherwise be inhibited by the presence of the semantic action.

Comment: Well done. It doesn't hurt documenting it once more in a (hopefully) searchable Q&A

Comment: I also read this and I'm still curious what the difference would be.

Thanks for this void of information!

Comment: @FrankPuck I fixed the documentation link to be much more precise. I usually paraphrase as _"semantic actions inhibit automatic attribute propagation (with `%=` initialization to override that"_ but apparently the documentation likes to come from the other end - emphasizing that `%=`-initialization enables automatic attribute propagation (and absense of semantic actions makes it  the default). They're equivalent in the end.

Comment: @FrankPuck Did that information help in any way? I'm asking because I'm answering a lot of your questions of late, but I never hear back unless it's complaints. I'm wondering if I'm doing the right things/things that are useful for you.

Comment: @sehe:

So the %= operator cancels the cancelation of default semantic actions. In above case qi::_val would contain a series of characters and my_string would contain the last character of the series?

Comment: @FrankPuck Exactly. I haven't tested this particular example, but it's the exact behaviour I expect to see